# void await function is preventing me from popping my second page. Says text field can't be null even when it's not null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm passing text data from page 2 to page 1 like so:

```
  void _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    // start the SecondScreen and wait for it to finish with a result
    final result = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MakeCircle(),
        ));
    // after the SecondScreen result comes back update the Text widget with it
    setState(() {
      text = result;
    });
  }
```

This is my app bar item handler:

```
Future<void> handleClick(String value) async {
    switch (value) {
      case 'Circles':
        _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(context);
        break;
```

The error pops up when I try exiting using the left arrow in the app bar.
"Failed Assertion. Data != null; a non-null String must be provided to a text widget."
It exits fine when I use my floating button to exit... I want to be able to exit using the left arrow as well... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant way of solving the problem but it works for now.

I assigned the following to my back arrow:

```
    onPressed: () {
      _sendDataBack(context);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    },
```

This works when I set a value of the text field to anything other than null.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use on will pop scope widget and return text value with pop.
Wrap your second page widget with WillPopScope

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    Navigator.pop(context, text);
    return false;
  }child:Scaffold(),
```